# Tensor product of duals

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Can we show $V^* \otimes W^* \simeq (V \otimes W)^*$, when $V$ or $W$ is finite-dimensional without referring to the basis?

I can inject $V^* \otimes W^*$ into $(V \otimes W)^*$ using the obvious way, the problem is other way around.

Comment: Since they are finite dimensional and they have the same dimension, as soon as you find an injection, it is clear that it is surjective as well.

Comment: And what in the case when V is finite-dimensional, but W isn't?

Comment: If $V,W$ are vector spaces on some field $F$, it is easy. Assume $V\simeq F^n$. Use the notation $Hom(V\otimes W, F)$ for $(V\otimes W)^\ast$. Then $Hom(V\otimes W, F) \simeq Hom(V, Hom(W,F)) \simeq V\otimes Hom(W,F) \simeq V^*\otimes W^*$.

Comment: How do you prove $V \simeq V^*$ without referring to the basis of $V$?

Comment: $V $ is finite dimensional, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I've only seen $V \sim V^*$ proven using dual bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a canonical linear map $V^* \otimes W^* \to (V \otimes W)^*$. It is an isomorphism when $W=K$ (both sides identify with $V^*$ and the linear map becomes the identity). The class of $W$s for which it is an isomorphism is closed under finite direct sums - this is because both sides are additive (contravariant) functors in $W$. It follows that it is an isomorphism for every finite-dimensional vector space $W$. Here, $V$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

A simple proof could go as follow. Let $k$ be the field these vector spaces are over.

1. First notice there is a natural linear map $\lambda_{V,W} : V^* \otimes W^* \to (V \otimes W)^*$ sending the tensor $\ell \otimes \ell'$ to the bilinear map $V \otimes W \to k$ given as
   $$v \otimes w \mapsto \ell(v)\ell'(w)$$
   It's easy to convince oneself this is is well-defined and bilinear, as claimed.
2. Then we just need to check this map is an isomorphism. Since $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, it suffices to prove it is injective. But notice $\lambda(\ell \otimes \ell') = 0$ implies either $\ell$ or $\ell'$ was zero to begin with, implying $\ell \otimes \ell' =0$. So we are done.

Two interesting observations:

1. The first map is obtained from the natural map witnessing functoriality of $\otimes$, given as $\mathrm{kVect}(A,B) \times \mathrm{kVect}(A',B') \to \mathrm{kVect}(A \otimes A', B \otimes B')$, which is defined 'componentwise'. We then compose this map with the isomorphism $k \otimes k \cong k$, represented by the multiplication of $k$.
2. I don't think we can conclude $\lambda_{V,W}$ is an isomorphism without the finite dimension assumption. In that case injectivity doesn't suffice to prove invertibility, so we'd also need to prove every functional $h:V \otimes W \to k$ arises as $\lambda(\ell \otimes \ell')$ of something, which seems unlikely in generality.